# How to edit the next file when VI doesn't have buffer support?

Tags: multiple-files

If I open multiple files in vi, and then when issuing the `:bnext` or `:bprev` or `:buffer` command I'm presented with `Feature not implemented`, how do I edit one of the other files that I have open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:n` will go to the next file when you open multiple ones